# Continuity of function - Proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

This is question 11 of Section 5.1 of Introduction to Real Analysis Fourth Edition by Robert G. Bartle.

**Question statement**

Let $K>0$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisy the condition that $|f(x)-f(y)|<K|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that f is continuous at every point $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:**
Let $x,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since the condition $|f(x)-f(y)|<K|x-y|$ holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds for $y=c$ because $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}>0$. Then, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<K|x-c|<K\dfrac{\epsilon}{K}=\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon$ and $c$ were arbitrary, we have that $f$ is continuous at any real $c$.

Could someone please check if this is correct? Thank you.

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Your proof is correct.

But a different approach, sequentially continuous iff $\epsilon , \delta $ continuous.

Let, $(x_n) $ be any sequence such that $(x_n) \to x $

Then, \begin{align}|f(x_n) -f(x) | & \le K|x_n -x| \to 0 \text {  as  } n\to \infty\end{align}

$\implies f(x_n) \to f(x) $

Hence, $f$ is continuous at any point $x\in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you very much for checking and for the alternative!

Comment: Although based on Balkys's proof being what I would expect to be the desired solution, my guess is that at this point in the book you'd need an $\epsilon,N$ proof instead of "$\to$".